# Why is viscous stress a tensorial quantity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, stress-strain, viscosity

In an incompressible fluid, the viscous stress (in Cartesian) is defined by
\begin{align}
\tau_{ij} = \eta(\partial_i v_j + \partial_j v_i)
\end{align}
for dynamic viscosity $\eta$ and velocity field $v_i$. If $\tau_{ij}$ was a tensor (strictly, a tensor field), it must obey the tensor transformation law
\begin{align}
\tau_{ij}(x) \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{\partial \bar{x}^a}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial \bar{x}^b}{\partial x^j} \bar{\tau}_{ab}(\bar{x})
\end{align}
However, the viscous stress obeys the transformation
\begin{align}
\tau_{ij} (x) = \eta\left(\frac{\partial \bar{x}^a}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial\bar{x}^b}{\partial x^j} \frac{\partial \bar{v}_a(\bar{x})}{\partial \bar{x}^b} + \frac{\partial^2 \bar{x}^b}{\partial x^i \partial x^j} \bar{v}_b \right) + (i \leftrightarrow j)
\end{align}
The second term spoils the transformation law. This is as opposed to the EM field tensor $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\nu$, where the antisymmetry cancels out the second term and it does obey the tensor transformation law.

While $\tau_{ij}$ behaves tensorially under global transformations (e.g. global rotations and translations), a transformation to polar coordinates, for example, would spoil the tensor transformation law. Why then do people refer to $\tau_{ij}$ as a tensor (tensor field)?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you have to specify under what kind of transformations a given tensor transforms under. Normally, in physics, people aren't explicit about this when it should be clear from context, but that can sometimes lead to confusion.

In this case, saying $\tau_{ij}$ is a tensor means that it is a tensor under global rotations (the way you've defined it with partial derivatives). It is only a tensor in Cartesian coordinates.

You can easily promote it to be a tensor under general coordinate transformations, by replacing the partial derivatives with [covariant derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols#Covariant_derivatives_of_tensors).

The fact that whether or not an object is a tensor depends on the notation we use to express it and the specific kind of transformations being considered might bother you, but it actually is something you may have come across before if you have studied special relativity from a geometric, 4-dimensional point of view. The electric and magnetic fields $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ are vectors under three dimensional rotations, but do not transform as vectors under Lorentz transformations. However, we can combine them into a covariant electromagnetic field-strength tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$, which does transform as a tensor under Lorentz transformations.

Comment: I don't think this is quite correct. Such a viewpoint would completely invalidate the principle that physics is geometric, i.e. expressible in coordinate-free notation. More concretely, a coordinate transformation to polar coordinates should not change any physical measurable.

Comment: @Aaron In order to use coordinate free notation, you should replace the partial derivatives with covariant derivatives. We **can** express the laws of physics in any coordinate system -- that's all that physics demands. Any particular mathematical way of writing the equations (for example, using partial derivatives) may be more restrictive.

Comment: Maybe more to the point, **you've already proven** in your question that $\tau_{ij}$ written with partial derivatives doesn't transform as a tensor under general coordinate transformations. The point of the covariant derivative is that you add an additional term to the derivative that transforms in such a way that it cancels the "bad term" you found in the transformation law of $\tau_{ij}$.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. My main complaint is that the term "tensor" should be equivalent to coordinate-free, but in your answer you've said that certain objects are only tensors under restricted class of transformations. I think more properly speaking, we should think of defining physical objects e.g. $\tau_{ij}$ in a particular coordinate system, and enforce that it obeys the tensor transformation law to obtain $\tau_{ij}'$ in every other coordinate system. However, the defining expression might not be manifestly covariant (as seen above).

Comment: @Aaron At least in physics (I don't know about mathematics), the same word "tensor" is commonly applied to (a) expressions like $\partial_\mu V_\nu$ which transform covariantly under global Lorentz transformations but not general coordinate transformations, and (b) expressions like $\nabla_\mu V_\nu$ which transform covariantly under general coordinate transformations. Whether (a) or (b) is meant is usually clear from context. That is the common usage, for better or worse.